# What units used in DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS?

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

What units are used in the usage metrics (`USED_SPACE` and `TABLESPACE_SIZE` columns) described in Oracle's `DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS` static data dictionary view?

The [Oracle Database Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5059.htm#I1023496) only tells they are the *"Total space consumed by the tablespace"* and *"Total size of the tablespace"*, without mentioning units. Are they in bytes? Megabytes? Blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blocks. Blocks are the units of the `DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS.USED_SPACE` and `DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS.TABLESPACE_SIZE`. The latter column accounts for possible AUTOEXTEND MAXSIZE.

EDIT: I'm not sure what is the meaning of USED_SPACE for undo tablespace though. For example:

```
SQL> SELECT tablespace_name, sum(blocks), status FROM dba_undo_extents GROUP BY tablespace_name, status ;

TABLESPACE_NAME                SUM(BLOCKS) STATUS
------------------------------ ----------- ---------
UNDOTBS1                               128 ACTIVE
UNDOTBS1                              5312 UNEXPIRED
UNDOTBS1                              8960 EXPIRED

SQL> select USED_SPACE from DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME='UNDOTBS1';

USED_SPACE
----------
      2864

SQL> show parameter block_size

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_block_size                        integer     8192
```

Comment: indeed it is the block size (at least in version 11.2.0.2.0). it is more precise to lookup the tablespace blockssize at dba_tablespaces.block_size because a tablespace can have blocksize that differs from the default blocksize of the datababase

Comment: Indeed. Any thoughts regarding undo metrics?

Comment: Undo blocks are always in the default block size for the database.  Undo blocks aren't "before images" - they contain records telling Oracle how to undo changes to blocks.

Answer (score -1):

I usually calculate so:

```
SELECT tbm.TABLESPACE_NAME,
   round(tbm.USED_SPACE * tb.BLOCK_SIZE /(1024*1024*1024),2) USED_SPACE_GB,
   round(tbm.TABLESPACE_SIZE * tb.BLOCK_SIZE /(1024*1024*1024),2) TABLESPACE_SIZE_GB,
   round((tbm.TABLESPACE_SIZE - tbm.USED_SPACE) * tb.BLOCK_SIZE /(1024*1024*1024),2) TABLESPACE_FREE_SIZE_GB,
   tbm.USED_PERCENT
FROM dba_tablespace_usage_metrics tbm
     join dba_tablespaces tb on tb.TABLESPACE_NAME = tbm.TABLESPACE_NAME
WHERE tbm.tablespace_name = 'tablespace_name'
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; while your query makes an assumption as to the units involved, it doesn't provide any official evidence that your units are correct.